# How to set up database for Django app on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

I'm a complete Heroku noob and I'm trying to set up a Django app on Heroku. I can't figure out what to enter for these settings in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

You can do it manually by looking at your database info in the dashboard or by running "heroku config" to see the DB configuration string.  But the best way by far is as detailed in the [Heroku Getting Started guide for Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django).  Add `dj-database-url==0.2.1` to your `requirements.txt` file and then:

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
```

in lieu of other database definitions.

Comment: Thanks! So you're saying that if I edit requirements.txt, then I should be able to copy and paste the above chunk of code into settings.py and not have to worry about filling out the database settings? I did that then tried running 'python manage.py syncdb' and got the following error: 

'ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.'

Comment: And then I tried setting the "ENGINE" value to 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' and it still gave me the same error... hmm.

Comment: Probably the problem is that this code is for running on Heroku where your DATABASE_ENV or some other system variable is already set.  I assume you are trying to run this first on your local build.  To resolve that issue, you can either pass a default URL string to dj_database_url.config() (see https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url ) or maintain a separate settings file for your local build.

Comment: Perhaps the ideal way to do it is to set up your settings file so that your "base" settings file works on Heroku but you can also have a local settings file that, using `import`, overrides only specific settings.  Explaining how to do that is a little complex for this space, but I believe it's the strategy detailed in the useful-for-beginners book "Two Scoops of Django" if you're looking for a resource like that.

Comment: Oh I see. Passing in the default URL string seems to work. Thanks!