# Django objects get deletes after a while automatically on heroku server

Tags: python, django, heroku

Does anyone know why my django saved objects getting deleted automatically after a while ' this happened like most of the times that i check my website and see's one of my files get's delete automatically from the server also the deleted objects are not the last saved objects but 3rd last or sometime's maybe 2nd last objects...

and i don't think it's a problem with my written code because this doesn't happens on local development server where usually i keep running the development server for more than 4-5 hours sometime's whole day..

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about files or db values? Either way, you can't save things to the filesystem on Heroku. For files, use S3; for db values, make sure you're using the PostgreSQL add-on rather than Heroku.

Comment: opps , that's what i mean actually saved objects(database objects) instance objects , also saved objects are not file's , but just text content's and url's again not files...

and dude i think heroku provides configured and activated PostgreSQL addon my default even for free user's already

Comment: Yes but you need to actually configure Django to use it. Have you? Show the DATABASES part of your settings.py.

Comment: don't know why are you asking this because otherwise not a single object would have existed till now which created more than 10 day's ago
but still have a look at my db configured lines in settings.py

Comment: No that's not true at all. The Heroku filesystem is *ephemeral*, which means it does not persist across dynos; but if your app was running on the same dyno for ten days, all objects would persist until then. In any case, as I said you are clearly using sqlite here instead of Postgres. See the Heroku docs or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868451/how-to-set-up-database-for-django-app-on-heroku) for how to set it up to use Postgres.

Comment: so do you mean i must use Postgres from now onward's and configured my app to use Postgres on local development server as well ...

but still confused , just checked now and realized all of my objects created from heroku server got deleted but the saved object's which i deployed from development server along with the database file still exist's ..

Comment: You can use sqlite locally if you want, but you must use Postgres on Heroku.

Comment: yeah got it thank's ' God bless you !

Answer (score 3):

This happens Due to **Dyno Manager**

The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many container based systems, such as Docker, operate.
To understand in depth check this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is not a cloud storage, so they delete all the uploaded data after some time.
Only the naked website remeains.